# primary datasource is not fetching data from jpaRepository in the spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

https://github.com/vikramsinghsengar007/SpringbootMultiDataSource

please check the above project as I am not getting any error for the primary dataSource but it's not fetching the records from the db. I have checked the log and getting proper sql.

Hibernate:

```
select product0_.id as id1_1_, product0_.brand as brand2_1_, product0_.madein as madein3_1_, product0_.name as name4_1_, product0_.price as price5_1_ 
from Product product0_
```

But the same configuration is working for the secondary DataSource.

Comment: Please include code that can be used to replicate your issue. Please don't link to any external sites that will change once the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got fixed. Actually, I forgot to use proper naming conventions.The problem was spring was overriding the primary datasource with the secondary as all the configurations was in the same package. And the second problem was I was providing wrong persistenceUnit while creating entitymanagefactory. It should be same as Mysql database.

Hope this will help someone.